# Core data save takes too long

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I've looked here to find a solution for my issue, for example:

[Core Data Saves and UI Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190473/core-data-saves-and-ui-performance)

[Why does Core Data take so long to save an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803324/why-does-core-data-take-so-long-to-save-an-object)

A lot of people have my problem but I've tried to use their solutions unsuccessfully.

Here is my problem:

I'm trying to save 10 Managed Objects in Core Data in background. I don't have any error, and all works really nice but...it takes 13 seconds to save 10 objects! I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

I need to save one hundred objects in my database, and if only 10 objects takes 13 seconds... I'm really scared about what is going to happen when I will try to save 100.

Here is my code:

First of all, I call my saving function in background:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateMessageList:) withObject:response];
```

And here I save the objects:

```
- (void)updateMessageList:(NSArray *)messageList
{
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]init];
    tmpContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [app persistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSError *error;

    int i = 0; //Counter to log how long it takes to insert a managedObject.

    for (MessageReadResponse* messageUpdate in messageList) {    
        NSLog(@"%d", i++);

        Message *message = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:MESSAGE_ENTITY
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:tmpContext];
        [message setState:STATE_ACTIVE];
        [message setFromName:[[messageUpdate from]name]];
        [message setFromSurname:[[messageUpdate from]surname]];
        [message setBody:[messageUpdate body]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Before saving");

    if (![tmpContext save:&error]) {
        ErrorLog(@"%@", error.description);
        [ErrorManagement synchronizeApplication];

        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"After saving");
}
```

And here is where I merge my managedObjectContext in the main thread:

```
- (void)manageDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *savedContext = [notification object];

    // Ignore change notifications for the main MOC
    if (__managedObjectContext == savedContext)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (__managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator != savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        // That's another database
        return;
    }

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [__managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    });
}
```

Here is my performance log:

```
2014-06-06 11:12:07.207 app-ios-client[260:8017] 0

2014-06-06 11:12:07.210 app-ios-client[260:8017] 1

2014-06-06 11:12:07.217 app-ios-client[260:8017] 2

2014-06-06 11:12:07.219 app-ios-client[260:8017] 3

2014-06-06 11:12:07.221 app-ios-client[260:8017] 4

2014-06-06 11:12:07.255 app-ios-client[260:8017] 5

2014-06-06 11:12:07.257 app-ios-client[260:8017] 6

2014-06-06 11:12:07.259 app-ios-client[260:8017] 7

2014-06-06 11:12:07.289 app-ios-client[260:8017] 8

2014-06-06 11:12:07.293 app-ios-client[260:8017] 9

2014-06-06 11:12:07.304 app-ios-client[260:8017] Before saving

2014-06-06 11:12:20.900 app-ios-client[260:8017] After saving
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDITED:**

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/qnzjolp49/full/) is my Instruments trace.

**EDITED 2:**

Thanks to Marcus Zarra, I've found that this method make my application works too slow:

```
-(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index];

    UITextView *gettingSizeLabel = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    gettingSizeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:FONT_SIZE];
    gettingSizeLabel.text = [[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path]body];

    Message *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
    if ([[info contentSize]isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH_NO_MEDIA, LABEL_TEXT_MAX_HEIGHT);

        CGSize expectedSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];

        if (expectedSize.height < LABEL_TEXT_MIN_HEIGHT_NO_MEDIA) {
            return LABEL_TEXT_MIN_HEIGHT_NO_MEDIA;
        }

        return  expectedSize.height;
    } else {
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH_MEDIA, LABEL_TEXT_MAX_HEIGHT);

        CGSize expectedSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];

        if (expectedSize.height < LABEL_TEXT_MIN_HEIGHT_MEDIA) {
            return LABEL_TEXT_MIN_HEIGHT_MEDIA;
        }

        return  expectedSize.height;
    }
}
```

This method I used to know the cell height, and without it, the app works really fast. I'm going to think about how to change this method to work faster...

Thanks a lot Marcus, for real!

Comment: I thought if you init your NSManagedObjectContext in mainthread, you should use it only in main. [Prove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527314/how-to-use-managedobjectcontext-with-threads)

Comment: `-updateMessageList` is called from a background thread and then the `NSManagedObjectContext` is initialized there.  The code is right although now antiquated going forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How big are these objects?  How much data are you trying to save?

What type of persistent store are you using? SQLite?

What is your UI doing with this data after you save?  Are you doing any kind of parsing of the data or display of the data?

What does Instruments say?  Where does it say the time is being spent?

These are the first questions.

Core Data in no way should be taking that long to save the data.  I suspect you are doing something in your User Interface that is being triggered by the save that is really taking the time.  Time Profiler in instruments will tell us what is going on.

While I would not write this the way you are doing it, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted therefore the issue must be somewhere else.  Instruments will tell us where to look.

### Update

Thank you for posting the trace, it confirms my suspicions.  If you look at where the time is being spent, 54% is in your `NSFetchedResultsController` and 20.6% is being spent in your `TimelineViewController`.  What this means is that the save is **very** quick and then your UI is reacting **very** slowly to the changes.  Turn off the merge changes notification to confirm.  From there I would suggest digging deeper into your UI in time profiler and find out why it is so incredibly slow.

Looks like you are doing some complex string manipulation and other things in there that are very CPU intensive.  Fix those and the speed will come back.

Comment: That code is called when I do a "Pull down to refresh" with an UIRefreshControl in a UITableView. In the main thread, when I do the "pull to refresh", I call a REST service in my server, and when I get the response, I save it in background with the code posted. I will check it with Instruments. Thanks

Comment: That did not answer any of the questions that I posted.  However, post your instruments profile results and we will see where the time is being spent.

Comment: - These objects are not big. In that moment I am trying to save 10 objects, but before that I've saved thousands of these objects (without performance issues). Yes, I'm using SQlite. After saving, my UI refresh the UITableView (in that table, the cells are custom cells, with a "bubble" to display the message) through the FetchedResultsControllerDelegate. I've edited my post to add the Instruments trace. Thanks

Comment: In my case one was `NSDateFormatter` which was killing the main thread. As @MarcusS.Zarra said, dig deeper!

Comment: Marcus, you are right. Without the merge changes notification the app works really fast... I'm going to check everything in my UI and then, when I find the error I will edit my post again with the solution. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @kemmitorz - This is exactly my issue.. Posting notification makes it slow. How did you overcome it? How are you posting the notification?

Comment: @nOObiOS profile your UI. Find out what is taking the time and eliminate it.  Using instruments is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you'll always save this amount of objects to Core Data don't bother yourself with multithreading. This won't affect your UI performace that much. Try implementing this in the main thread just like any basic tutorial tells you to do.

If you really badly want this multithreading thing try looking at this [tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/). You'll see that main `NSManagedObjectContext` is for your UI and any other custom context should be for dealing with data.

For me, you're trying to do something too good. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code he wrote. He is creating a thread confined context, writing to it and saving all in one method.